# Need to convert listview item of string type to long variable

Tags: c#, listview

I have a listview(lvwView1) of 8 columns and 3 rows. i need to convert the last subitem(7th item) in very first row(0th row) to long type. I tried multiple ways like:

```
long var= (long)Convert.ToDouble(lvwView1.Items[0].SubItems[7].Text);
long var = convert.toInt64(lvwView1.items[0].subitems[7].tostring());
long var = long.Parse(lvwView1.Items[0].SubItems[7].ToString());
```

Moving forward, i need to convert the last subitem(7th item) of Listview to long on subitem selected in listview (event - lvwView_SelectedIndexChanged).

Can Someone help in converting listview item of string type to long variable

Comment: Are you getting some kind of exception or compile error?

Comment: You probably shouldn't use "var" as a variable name. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer. The conversion specified below worked out for me

```
long lVal = (long)Convert.ToDouble(lvwView1.Items[0].SubItems[7].Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

inside your event try below

```
long val = long.Parse(lvwView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[7].Text);
```